# Three.js Extending geometry

Tags: three.js

I would like to know how I can extend a geometry to a length.

Like a pipe in 2d that I will give a length/height.
See image
[Wood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHsba.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with scaling:

`mesh.scale.set( 3, 4, 5 )`. The number is the factor which you use to calculate the new size from the old. With `mesh.scale.set( 3, 4, 5 )`the mesh gets 3 times bigger on the x-axis, 4 times bigger on the y-axis und 5 times bigger on the z-axis.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.